# How do you create an HTML button from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project where we are trying to create a website for signing up for music auditions. Part of that involves displaying buttons with audition days available that once clicked, display buttons that each have a time assigned to them. Once these buttons are clicked, they change their functionality and do not submit anything.

Is this a feasible concept? If so how do I execute this?

Comment: Some introductory tutorials on HTML and JavaScript would be a good place to start.  Yes, having buttons that do things is a feasible concept.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating some more?

Comment: document.createElement('button'); But tutorials should be the best place to start indeed.

Comment: Here is a useful tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

Comment: Also note that *creating* these elements might not even be the ideal approach.  It's too broad for us to really know, but keeping the markup more static and responding to events in a more dynamic way might be better.  For example, you might show/hide a button rather than create/destroy a button.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var btn = document.createElement('button');
```

Or:

```
var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.type = 'button';
```

Answer (score 0):

[Look into the `document.createElement()` function in Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp). A sample usage would be:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="div1"></div>

    <script>
    function createButton(id, text) {
      var b = document.createElement("input");
      b.type = "button";
      b.id = id;
      b.value = text;
      b.onclick += button_click; //assigns the button_click function to the click event of the button.
      var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
      div1.appendChild(b); //add the button to the page in the div
    }

    function button_click(e) {
      e = window.event ? window.event : e;
      var b = e.target;
      b.disabled = true;
    }

    createButton("button1", "Click Me");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This example also uses the [event object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) and the `disabled` property of the element, as well as the [`document.getElementById()` function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp).

The `createButton()` function example can be called from any other function, but in this case, it will always add a new button the `div` element.

The `e.target` usage here allows you to get the button that was click, in essence, the target of the event. The `e = window.event ? window.event : e;` line is a cross-browser way to ensure that the JavaScript event object has been picked up.

This example likely will not solve your specific issue, but it does answer your question of whether this is feasible in HTML/JavaScript.